# Jquery. change element position onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, indexing

I have a question from jQuery. I want to change the position of div onclick. I have 4 divs, and four menus. When I click on menu, I wanna the div come to first position. This is html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Untitled</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="my.css">
<script src="jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <ul>
    <li id= "home"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li id= "about"><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li id= "products"><a href="#">Products</a></li>
    <li id= "services"><a href="#">Services</a></li>
    <li id= "contact"><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div id = "newdiv"   style="height:400px; width:700px; background-color:red;       margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; "></div>
  <div id = "newdiv1"  style="height:400px; width:700px; background-color:blue;      margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; "></div>
  <div id = "newdiv2"  style="height:400px; width:700px; background-color:yellow;    margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; "></div>
  <div id = "newdiv3"  style="height:400px; width:700px; background-color:green;     margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; "></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Now when I click about, I wanna the second div appear in first position. I am not very familiar with jQuery, and I tried to do it with index, but no success. How can I do that?

Comment: what do you want when contact is clicked ?

Answer (score 2):

First, you'll have to wrap all your `div` into an element. I call it the `mainMan` :

```
<div id="mainMan">
    <div id="newdiv" style="height:400px; width:700px; background-color:red;       margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; "></div>
    <div id="newdiv1" style="height:400px; width:700px; background-color:blue;      margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; "></div>
    <div id="newdiv2" style="height:400px; width:700px; background-color:yellow;    margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; "></div>
    <div id="newdiv3" style="height:400px; width:700px; background-color:green;     margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; "></div>
</div>
```

Then, write an event handler like this for the change to happen when you click on `a` in `li` :

```
$("ul").on("click", "li a", function () {
    var index = $(this).parent("li").index();
    $("#mainMan").find("div:eq(" + index + ")").prependTo("#mainMan")
});
```

The trick is using `index` to match the corresponding `div` with `:eq()` selector, then using `prepend` which will move the chosen element to the front.

The last thing you need to do is add a css styles for the common styles in a stylesheet and keep bgcolor alone inline.

```
<div id="mainMan">
    <div id="newdiv" style=" background-color:red;"></div>
    <div id="newdiv1" style="background-color:blue;"></div>
    <div id="newdiv2" style="background-color:yellow;"></div>
    <div id="newdiv3" style="background-color:green;"></div>
</div>
```

And your CSS :

```
#mainMan > div {
    height:400px;
    width:700px;
    margin-right:auto;
}
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/hungerpain/gsMyA/1/

Answer (score 0):

Add onclick function to each `<li>` that calls its jquery function then add any css attribute depends on your required position.

**example :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <head>
    <title>Untitled</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="my.css">
    <script src="jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <script>
      function MoveHome(){
          $(this).position='relative';
          //Or you can add any other css attribute
      }
    </script>

  </head>
  <body>
   <ul>
    <li id= "home" onclick="MoveHome"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li id= "about"><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li id= "products"><a href="#">Products</a></li>
    <li id= "services"><a href="#">Services</a></li>
    <li id= "contact"><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
   </ul>

   <div id = "newdiv"   style="height:400px; width:700px; background-color:red;       margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; "></div>
   <div id = "newdiv1"  style="height:400px; width:700px; background-color:blue;      margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; "></div>
   <div id = "newdiv2"  style="height:400px; width:700px; background-color:yellow;    margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; "></div>
   <div id = "newdiv3"  style="height:400px; width:700px; background-color:green;     margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; "></div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Working Demo http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/gsMyA/2/

```
$("ul").on("click", "li a", function () {
    var index = ($(this).parent("li").index() == 0) ? '': $(this).parent("li").index();
    $("#mainMan").find("#newdiv"+index).prependTo("#mainMan");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want like this, DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/zsYua/

```
$('li a').on('click', function () {
    var id = $(this).parent('li').attr('id');
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("div#" + id).offset().top
    },'slow');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

first you need to wrap all your div into a section like:

then following jquery code will do the trick:

```
$('ul li a').click(function(){
var index = $(this).parent("li").index();
$("#container").find("div:eq(" + index + ")").prependTo("#container") 
});
```

In this method we are getting the index of the 'li' we are clicking on and then calling the same index div inside the section using jquery **'eq()'** selector which takes the index value of the selected 'li'.
  'prependTo()' will add the selected div to the top of the section container.